# How to create or use apps private directory on Removable storage android

Tags: android, storage

`getExternalFilesDir(null)` is returning the path of the **emulated sd card** i.e internal to the phone but not the path removable **sd card**

how i can find the data directory of app on removable storage

Answer (score 0):

'External' means not internal and internal means private if we translate Android English to real life English. External storage is the place that all apps can access and use.

Since the question is a bit vague then the answer must be.

SD card can be mapped to internal storage or external storage, but this is fairly new technology.

If you want to access SD card using in versions earlier than Android 5.0 (API 21) then you can use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();`

Otherwise you must use [Storage Access Framework](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html) to do it.

Comment: getExternalFilesDir(null) is returing "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<package name>/files" path

but i want to store my files at "/storage/sdcard1/Android/data/<package_name>/file"

some of the apps are accessing this path without any further permission for example shareit

Comment: I've never said anything about getExternalFilesDir.

Comment: i know you have not said any thing about getExternalFilesDir,  i am trying to explain you my problem what exactly i need.

Comment: getExternalFilesDir does what it supposed to do. Gives you external files.